# 413 request entity too large issue in HTTP Get method call

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, http-get

Please don't mistake it as already asked question. The main difference here is, this issue is coming in Get method call. All the solutions discussed here or other places talks about either POST method or multipart form data.

Configuration I have provided is as below:

```
String url = env.getProperty(ApplicationConstants.PMCC_MANAGER_REGION_QUERY_URL);
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).queryParam("inTIS_PMA_NUMBER","ALL");
URI uri = builder.build().toUri();
RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplateBuilder().build();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);


private RestTemplateBuilder getRestTemplateBuilder() {
        Integer connectionTimeOut = 2000;
        Integer readTimeOut = 3000;
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        restTemplateBuilder.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeOut);
        restTemplateBuilder.setReadTimeout(readTimeOut);

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory(); 
        factory.setBufferRequestBody(false); 

        restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(factory);
        return restTemplateBuilder;
    }
```

This code is part of Spring Boot application and deployed in WebLogic server.